# Getting null object on console for the first run in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a button and I'm calling an arrow function contentLoad on click of that button. I've two objects. One is 'obj' and other is 'content' which is a mere copy of 'obj'.

> this.setState({content: obj})

When i print both of them on console. The other one i.e the copied one is null for the first click. However everything looks good after the first click.

The entire project is [here](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/nested-objects)

And the js code is [this](https://github.com/tmtanzeel/nested-objects/blob/master/src/components/Reader/Reader.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A lesser known fact is that `this.setState` is an asyncronous function in React.
It takes a second parameter which is a callback to to execute once the state is actually set.

```
this.setState(new_state, optional_callback_function)
```

So, when you see `null` being printed when logging `content`, it is because the state has not been set before calling the `console.log` and you simply see the initial value, `null`.

To remedy this and see the correct value everytime, you could refactor your code like so:

```
this.setState({content: obj}, () => {
   console.log(this.state.content);
})
```

Answer (score 3):

According to manual [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html):

"Calls to setState are asynchronous - don’t rely on this.state to reflect the new value immediately after calling setState. Pass an updater function instead of an object if you need to compute values based on the current state (see below for details)."

Comment: On passing an updater function I'm getting a warning at console. 

Warning:
Do not mutate state directly, Use setState() react/no-direct-mutation-state in React JS

Answer (score 3):

setState is asynchronous, so it probably did not complete before the console.log which immediately follows it.

setState allows a callback function to be passed which will be invoked after the state has been modified. Try this with a callback instead:

```
this.setState({content: obj}, () => console.log(this.state.content));
```